# Hide contacts from Contacts, but still have them appear when the contact calls

Tags: contacts, caller-id

There are some contacts I almost never dial, and never *wanna* dial, but I still don't want them to show up as unknown when they call me. Otherwise I could just put them in a group and hide them.

Would it be possible to just *hide them* but let call manager or whatever handles the incoming call still display their detail? (or is that too much having my cake and eating it too?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way I used to do it (make sure all of your contacts are backed up to Google):

1. Delete all non google contacts.
2. Add contacts to phone that you don't want to appear.
3. Delete the contacts from Google that you just added to your phone.
4. In you contact book:

   > Menu Button > Contacts to Display > Google Only

Now your contact book will only show your Google contacts, but your phone contacts will show up if the person calls you. This is a little inconvienent if you like to use both your google and phone contacts for different things.

NOTE: this process can be reversed to get the opposite effect (store main contacts on phone, store contacts of people you don't want to see on Google).

Comment: I'm testing and it seems just hiding the contacts from "Contacts to Display" setting works too. I hid everything so Contacts appeared blank but calls and messages are assigned names according to "hidden" contacts. Awesome.